# Compare only day / month / year portion of a timestamp field

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I am creating a view for a certain table, where rows have `timestamp` fields (`planned_ts`). The view needs to be sorted according to these timestamps, but since the application is only interested by the date and not the time, the result look sometimes random, especially when sorting over multiple fields.

The question I have is, if I have this query (for example) :

```
SELECT *
  FROM tblFoo
 WHERE ...
 ORDER BY planned_ts ASC NULLS LAST, priority ASC
```

(**NOTE**: where `priority` is an `integer` field, lower means more higher priority.)

How can I change the order clause, so it does not consider the time, as if every timestamps were at `00:00:00.000`? I am aware that I can use functions in the sort clause, but I'm not sure how to do this in PostgreSQL.

Comment: use date_trunc();  http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use date_trunc() function..

```
SELECT
  *
FROM tblFoo
WHERE ...
ORDER BY date_trunc('day', planned_ts) ASC NULLS LAST, priority ASC
```

Please see [the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html) for the functions if necessary.